# How to run Vue app on localhost with --remote-debugging-port flag?

Tags: google-chrome, vscode-debugger

I am trying to use Chrome Debugger for VS Code with my Vue application. To use it in the `attach` mode, it is required to run chrome with `--remote-debugging-port` flag. However, when I open my app on `localhost:8080`, I see this:

[image]

Clicking the `Inspectable pages` tab redirects me to chrome devtools view but non-related to my application in any way:

[image]

Is there any way I can make the feature work and be able to view my app at `localhost:8080` as usual and attach my Chrome Debugger to it?